# draw values in multiple canvases at the same time

Tags: java, javafx

I have a pane where I draw a lot of values in many canvases. A Canvas consists of three lines of values. Right now I fill the canvases one by one but this isn't fast enough. Especially when I want to show a longer duration (2min in the picture, max duration is 30min). Every second, that is drawn, can be selected to show the area more detailed. Is there a way I can draw all canvases simultaneously or just in a faster way? This is an example of how I go through to draw the lines in the canvas right now.

```
for(Canvas canvas : allCanvases)
{
    GraphicContext gc = canvas.getGraphicContext2D();
    ...
    for(int line = 0; line < 3; line++)
    {
        ...
        for(int sec = 0; sec < duration; sec++)
        {
            value = canvasValues[line][sec];
            ...
            gc.strokeLine(sec, value);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]